# Cannot boot Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS after a normal update

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem

After doing a regular update using **Software Updater**, Ubuntu froze and stopped responding to any input from keyboard. I tried to do a fresh restart, but now I cannot go beyond the blinking cursor and black screen that does not respond to any input from keyboard.

I tried to use Live CD and here are the outputs.

**sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160040803840 bytes, 312579695 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0xc8019649

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63 308512003 308511941 147.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       308512260 312576704   4064445     2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       308512323 312576704   4064382     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors Units:
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x0002f0af
```

**sudo blkid**

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="96E9-5126" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0002f0af-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="c8019649-01"
/dev/sda5: PARTUUID="c8019649-05"
```

**sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list**

```
/dev/loop0 squashfs         /rofs          
/dev/sda1                   (not mounted)  
/dev/sda5                   (not mounted)  
/dev/sdb1  vfat    UBUNTU 16_0 /cdrom      96E9-5126
```

It is clear that there is a problem with the partitioning of the hard disk. What can I do to fix it?

Edit: I tried to use **Boot-Repair** (see [the log](http://paste2.org/GcpgcVkJ)) but the problem still persists!

Comment: Could you post the URL from Boot-Repair?

Comment: Sure, http://paste2.org/GcpgcVkJ

Comment: Is it safe to use "gnome-disks" without damaging the contents of the HDD?

Comment: You can damage contents of the HDD with any partitioning SW like gnome-disks, GParted etc. when using them incorrectly. Thanks for the Boot-Repair log. It looks like the bootloader and the header of the `/dev/sda1` are damaged. While GRUB can be restored using Boot-Repair, I have no experience in restoring a damaged file system. I hope someone else can help, I’ll edit the question to get more attention.

Comment: There are no working file systems on your drive. You can try to salvage any remaining data but you'll need to install Ubuntu and Windows from scratch (after the data recovery).